# Using only the DB part of Django

Tags: python, django, orm

Does somebody know how "modular" is Django? Can I use just the ORM part, to get classes that map to DB tables and know how to read/write from these tables?

If not, what would you recommend as "the Python equivalent of Hibernate"?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302651/use-only-some-parts-of-django

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The short answer is: no, you can't use the Django ORM separately from Django.

The long answer is: yes, you can if you are willing to load large parts of Django along with it. For example, the database connection that is used by Django is opened when a request to Django occurs. This happens when a signal is sent so you could ostensibly send this signal to open the connection without using the specific request mechanism. Also, you'd need to setup the various applications and settings for the Django project.

Ultimately, it probably isn't worth your time. [SQL Alchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) is a relatively well known Python ORM, which is actually more powerful than Django's anyway since it supports multiple database connections and connection pooling and other good stuff.

---

**Edit:** in response to James' criticism elsewhere, I will clarify what I described in my original post. While it is gratifying that a major Django contributor has called me out, I still think I'm right :)

First off, consider what needs to be done to use Django's ORM separate from any other part. You use one of the [methods](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/) described by James for doing a basic setup of Django. But a number of these methods don't allow for using the `syncdb` command, which is required to create the tables for your models. A settings.py file is needed for this, with variables not just for `DATABASE_*`, but also `INSTALLED_APPLICATIONS` with the correct paths to all models.py files.

It is possible to roll your own solution to use `syncdb` without a settings.py, but it requires some advanced knowledge of Django. Of course, you don't need to use `syncdb`; the tables can be created independently of the models. But it is an aspect of the ORM that is not available unless you put some effort into setup.

Secondly, consider how you would create your queries to the DB with the standard `Model.objects.filter()` call. If this is done as part of a view, it's very simple: construct the `QuerySet` and view the instances. For example:

```
tag_query = Tag.objects.filter( name='stackoverflow' )
if( tag_query.count() > 0 ):
    tag = tag_query[0]
    tag.name = 'stackoverflowed'
    tag.save()
```

Nice, simple and clean. Now, without the crutch of Django's request/response chaining system, you need to initialise the database connection, make the query, then close the connection. So the above example becomes:

```
from django.db import reset_queries, close_connection, _rollback_on_exception
reset_queries()
try:
    tag_query = Tag.objects.filter( name='stackoverflow' )
    if( tag_query.count() > 0 ):
        tag = tag_query[0]
        tag.name = 'stackoverflowed'
        tag.save()
except:
    _rollback_on_exception()
finally:
    close_connection()
```

The database connection management can also be done via Django signals. All of the above is defined in [django/db/**init**.py](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/__init__.py). Other ORMs also have this sort of connection management, but you don't need to dig into their source to find out how to do it. SQL Alchemy's connection management system is documented in the [tutorials](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/ormtutorial.html) and elsewhere.

Finally, you need to keep in mind that the database connection object is local to the current thread at all times, which may or may not limit you depending on your requirements. If your application is not stateless, like Django, but persistent, you may hit threading issues.

In conclusion, it is a matter of opinion. In my opinion, both the limitations of, and the setup required for, Django's ORM separate from the framework is too much of a liability. There are perfectly viable dedicated ORM solutions available elsewhere that are designed for library usage. Django's is not.

Don't think that all of the above shows I dislike Django and all it's workings, I really do like Django a lot! But I'm realistic about what it's capabilities are and being an ORM library is not one of them.

P.S. Multiple database connection support is being [worked](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/1142) on. But it's not there now.

Comment: Erm. I suspect you're rather misinformed. I'll post a longer answer below explaining why.

Comment: Your update further demonstrates that you're misinformed.  Any ORM requires configuration, Django's settings.py is no onerous than most (less than many).  And your "code sample" is ridiculous: if you want transactions do "from django.db import transaction"; the API is both clean and documented.

Comment: As I said, I consider the setup required for Django's ORM too onerous. This is just my opinion on the matter. My sample uses the precise same methods that Django does per request, as listed in the linked py file. The point still stands - Django is not an ORM library.

Comment: I think you have some interesting points, but still this is not answering the question correctly. You can easily just use Django's ORM in any python applications. There may be other better suited libraries for this but that's not the question here.

Comment: -1 as this answer is (no longer?) true for the most part. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/20968008/176186.

Comment: With django>=1.6 you can set AUTOCOMMIT and can handle at app level finer transaction isolation with transaction.atomic() without the need to write a mimicker of TransactionMiddleware, you can also use persistent connections although they're less powerful than SQL Alchemy connection pooler it fits most cases. I'm working with Django18 ORM as standalone and honestly I find no trouble. It allows using code in other smaller Django projects seamlessly. You have awesome migrations tool shipped. If you can choose Postgresql then use PgBouncer for pooling and you're done without learning another ORM.

Comment: Quite confusing that this is the accepted answer as it is largely incorrect.  I've used the Django ORM outside of Django for many command-line apps, and it's very straightforward without using MVC or any other Django components.

Comment: Regarding only the ORM functionality, Django (1.11) docs specifically mention how to do this here (I have successfully implemented this on Django 1.7 as well): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage.

Comment: I completely agree with you. It's quite annoying that Django ORM is not a standalone library when it could be. I don't want to bring complete web layer to my standalone script which needs DB only. Although there are hacks to make it run you still carry around the whole Django framework. Sharing Django models between different apps is also cumbersome because `Meta`s `managed` needs to be `True` only in the owning app. Perhaps using SQLAlchemy from the start future proofs your code better if you decide to reuse schema outside of Django.

Answer (score 98):

If you like Django's ORM, it's perfectly simple to use it "standalone"; I've [written up several techniques for using parts of Django outside of a web context](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/), and you're free to use any of them (or roll your own).

Shane above seems to be a bit misinformed on this and a few other points -- for example, Django *can* do multiple different databases, it just doesn't *default* to that (you need to do a custom manager on the models which use something other than the "main" DB, something that's not too hard and there are recipes floating around for it). It's true that Django itself doesn't do connection management/connection pooling, but personally I've always used external tools for that anyway (e.g., `pgpool`, which rocks harder than anything built in to an ORM ever could).

I'd suggest spending some time reading up and possibly trying a few likely Google searches (e.g., the post I linked you to comes up as the top result for "standalone Django script") to get a feel for what will actually best suit your needs and tastes -- it may be Django's ORM isn't right for you, and you shouldn't use it if it isn't, but unfortunately there's a lot of misinformation out there which muddies the waters.

**Editing to respond to Shane:**

Again, you seem to be misinformed: SQLAlchemy needs to be configured (i.e., told what DB to use, how to connect, etc.) before you can run queries with it, so how is the fact that Django needs similar configuration (accomplished via your choice of methods -- you **do not** need to have a full Django settings file) any disadvantage?

As for multiple DB support, you seem to be confused: the support is there at a low level. The query object -- not `QuerySet`, but the underlying `Query` object it will execute knows what DB it's connecting to, and accepts a DB connection as one of its initialization arguments. Telling one model to use one DB and another model to use another is as simple as setting up one method on a manager which passes the right connection info down into the `Query`. True, there's no higher-level API for this, but that's not the same as "no support" and not the same as "requires custom code" (unless you'd argue that configuring multiple DBs explicitly in SQLAlchemy, required if you want multiple DBs, is also "custom code").

As for whether you end up *indirectly* using things that aren't in `django.db`, well, so what? The fact that `django.db` imports bits of, say, `django.utils` because there are data structures and other bits of code which are useful for more than just an ORM is fine as far as I'm personally concerned; one might as well complain if something has external dependencies or makes use of standard Python libraries instead of being 100% self-contained.

Comment: I would argue that his question is far more specific - he wants to use Django's ORM, and nothing else. In other words, import django.db and away he goes. That isn't possible. As regards multiple DB support, see ticket http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/1142. Custom code is not support!

Comment: I've edited my original post in response to your point of view. That's service, that is :)

Comment: His question specifically asks for the ORM, nothing more. This limits it to database interactions only. Multiple DBs: SQL Alchemy has documented support, Django does not. You can do what you describe but if it's not documented, I don't consider it part of the official API. Hence, not supported.

Comment: So if SA calls into any module not named `sqlalchemy`, would you say that it's suddenly not "ORM, nothing more"? Or would you accept that maybe there might be libraries it imports as part of doing its work, which in no way compromise its "ORM" nature (also, SQLALchemy isn't "ORM, nothing more")?

Comment: can you respond to Shane's claim that your method disables syncdb? I'm a django novice...

Comment: I just used Django's ORM in a standalone python script. Configuration was quite easy and far from complicated.

Comment: SQLAlchemy "configuration" is still far simpler - just call a function to connect the database. No need for a settings.py file and any particular file structure, nor to keep the model separated from the rest of the code. I'm getting the feeling that Django fans are trying to force a positive answer in fear this may be seen as a defect in Django, which is not. Django and SQLAlchemy are very different beasts.

Comment: Putting aside the issue of how to set this up, can you clarify that this should be a "safe" way to access the database? In other words, what if I am modifying it from the django admin interface and an automated standalone script happens to run at exactly the same time?

Comment: So James' answer, his role on core aside, is arguably more correct and consequently much more upvoted than the currently accepted answer (+77 to +9).  Yet it sits at the bottom below several less relevant answers, which I find confusing to others who stumble upon this question.  I wonder if it's possible for the accepted answer to be updated to this one by OP or the community.

Answer (score 10):

(I'm reporting my solution because my question said to be a duplicate)

Ah ok I figured it out and will post the solutions for anyone attempting to do the same thing.

This solution assumes that you want to create new models.

First create a new folder to store your files. We'll call it "standAlone". Within "standAlone", create the following files:

```
__init__.py
myScript.py
settings.py
```

Obviously "myScript.py" can be named whatever.

Next, create a directory for your models.

We'll name our model directory "myApp", but realize that this is a normal Django application within a project, as such, name it appropriately to the collection of models you are writing.

Within this directory create 2 files:

```
__init__.py
models.py
```

Your going to need a copy of manage.py from an either an existing Django project or you can just grab a copy from your Django install path:

```
django\conf\project_template\manage.py
```

Copy the manage.py to your /standAlone directory. Ok so you should now have the following structure:

```
\standAlone
    __init__.py
    myScript.py
    manage.py
    settings.py
\myApp
    __init__.py
    models.py
```

**Add the following to your myScript.py file:**

```
# settings.py
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure(
    DATABASE_ENGINE    = "postgresql_psycopg2",
    DATABASE_NAME      = "myDatabase",
    DATABASE_USER      = "myUsername",
    DATABASE_PASSWORD  = "myPassword",
    DATABASE_HOST      = "localhost",
    DATABASE_PORT      = "5432",
    INSTALLED_APPS     = ("myApp")
)

from django.db import models
from myApp.models import *
```

**and add this to your settings.py file:**

```
    DATABASE_ENGINE    = "postgresql_psycopg2"
    DATABASE_NAME      = "myDatabase"
    DATABASE_USER      = "myUsername"
    DATABASE_PASSWORD  = "myPassword"
    DATABASE_HOST      = "localhost"
    DATABASE_PORT      = "5432",
    INSTALLED_APPS     = ("myApp")
```

**and finally your myApp/models.py:**

```
# myApp/models.py
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
     field = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

and that's it. Now to have Django manage your database, in command prompt navigate to our /standalone directory and run:

```
manage.py sql MyApp
```

Comment: Makes me wonder: why is the same information contained in settings.py and MyScript.py ?

Comment: Great solution! :) It also shows SQLAlchemy is far easier to use, but if OP wants to use more than just the ORM, or share the data model with a web application written in Django, it may be worth it.

Comment: @Ber - It doesn't have to be.  Check my solution.  It's relatively similar, but also demonstrates a syncdb and fewer moving parts.

Answer (score 10):

I'm using django ORM without a settings file.  Here's how:

In the stand-alone app launcher file:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

#Django settings
settings.configure(DEBUG=False,
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': '/path/to/dbfile',
            'USER': '',
            'PASSWORD': '',
            'HOST': '',
            'PORT': '',
        }
    },
    INSTALLED_APPS = ('modelsapp',)
)

if not os.path.exists('/path/to/dbfile'):
    sync = ['manage.py', 'syncdb']
    execute_from_command_line(sync)
```

Now you just need a `./modelsapp` folder containing an `__init__.py` and a `models.py`.  The config uses sqlite for simplicity sake, but it could use any of the db backends.

Folder structure:

```
./launcher.py
./modelsapp
    __init__.py
    models.py
```

Note that you don't have to have a manage.py proper.  The `import execute_from_command_line` just finds it.

Answer (score 9):

You can certainly use various parts of Django in a stand-alone fashion. It is after-all just a collection of Python modules, which you can import to any other code you would like to use them.

I'd also recommend looking at [SQL Alchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) if you are only after the ORM side of things.

Comment: In my opinion, SQL Alchemy is much much worse than Django ORM in terms of usability and simplicity. For instance, it doesn't do a coercion and allows setting a string to a DateTime field. It remains a string if you try to access it later without refreshing the object.

Answer (score 7):

## Using Django 2.0 ORM - One File Required

```
from myproject.config import parse_config
from django import setup as django_setup
from django.conf import settings as django_settings

"""
Requirements:
  ODBC Driver: https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=36434
  Django Engine: https://pypi.org/project/django-pyodbc-azure/
"""

config = parse_config()
django_settings.configure(
    DEBUG=True,
    DATABASES={
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
            'NAME': config.database_name,
            'HOST': config.database_server,  # exclude '\\MSSQLSERVER'
            'USER': config.database_username,
            'PASSWORD': config.database_password,
            'PORT': '',
            'AUTOCOMMIT': False,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'driver': 'ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server',
            },
        },
    })
django_setup()


from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'myapp'  # each model will require this
```

Comment: I faced RuntimeError: Model class XYZ doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [SQLAlchemy](http://sqlalchemy.org). It should do all the ORM stuff, as well as basic SQL stuff.

Comment: +1 - Not only will using this free you of chopping up a framework like Django, but it is better and more fully featured than Django's ORM.

Comment: His last sentence indicates his options are open.

Comment: bigmattyh, from everything except the first bit I don't think I did miss the point. The OP wants ORM.

Comment: +1: "the Python equivalent of Hibernate" is SQLAlchemy.  Or SQLObject.

Answer (score 3):

I understand this post is old, but in recent years I've found a smaller solution works great:

```
import os, sys
import django

# sys.path.append('/abs/path/to/my-project/)
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')
django.setup()

# Use
from myapp import models
kv = models.KeyValue()
```

Ensuring this script runs in the applicable relative directory, or apply the sys PATH append to ensure the modules are resolved.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

This example is as simple as it gets. I already have a django app called thab up and running.  I want to use the django orm in free standing python scripts and use the same models as I'm using for web programming. Here is an example:

```
# nothing in my sys.path contains my django project files
import sys
sys.path.append('c:\\apython\\thab')  # location of django app (module) called thab          where my settings.py and models.py is
# my settings.py file is actualy in c:\apython\thab\thab
from thab import settings as s  # need it because my database setting are there
dbs = s.DATABASES
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure(DATABASES=dbs) # configure can only be called once
from thab.models import *
boards = Board.objects.all()
print 'all boards:' + str(boards) # show all the boards in my board table
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably I'm quite late with my answer, but it's better late than never.

Try this simple package:
https://github.com/serglopatin/django-models-standalone

How to use:

1. download
2. install

   ```
   python setup.py install
   ```
3. create project

   ```
   django-models-standalone startproject myproject
   ```
4. adjust files settings.py (DATABASES) and models.py, then migrate if tables not created
5. use djando models in your application (example.py)

Answer (score 1):

```
import django
from django.conf import settings
from backend_mock.admin import settings as s
settings.configure(
    DATABASES=s.DATABASES,
    INSTALLED_APPS=('backend_mock.admin.mocker', )
)
django.setup()
```

take a look at this, it's working for django version gte 1.8.x

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me in **Django > 1.4**

Assuming that your standalone script is your django project DIR.

Just copy this in a **conf.py** file (you can give it any name).

```
import os
import sys
import django

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(BASE_DIR) 
#sys.path.append('c:\\apython\\thab')
 # location of django app (module) called thab          where my settings.py and models.py is
# my settings.py file is actualy in c:\apython\thab\thab
from elsaserver import settings as s  # need it because my database setting are there
dbs = s.DATABASES
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure(
    DATABASES=dbs,
    INSTALLED_APPS=('core.apps.CoreConfig', )) #add all the apps you need here
django.setup()
```

Then import the **conf.py** in your python script.

This is the project structure:

```
mydjangoproject
    |
    > app1
    > core
    > app2
    > standalone
    | | __init__.py  
    | | conf.py  
    | | myscript.py
    > manage.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it outside a django project.
But there are there things you should be aware of.

#### 1. Multiple database router.

A router looks like:

```
class Router(object):
    app_label = ''

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == self.app_label:
            return self.app_label
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == self.app_label:
            return self.app_label
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label == self.app_label or obj2._meta.app_label == self.app_label:
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model=None, **hints):
        if app_label == self.app_label:
            return db == self.app_label
    return None
```

You can use meta class to dynamic create router.

```
def add_db(db_conf):
    app_label = 'al_' + str(uuid4())

    settings.DATABASES[app_label] = db_conf

    router_class_name = 'Router' + app_label.capitalize()
    setattr(
        settings,
        router_class_name,
        type(router_class_name, (Router,), dict(app_label=app_label)),
    )
    settings.DATABASE_ROUTERS.append(
        '.'.join([settings.__name__, router_class_name])
    )
    connections.close_all()
return app_label
```

### 2. Django settings.

the most important key is `TIME_ZONE`. `DatetimeField` and `DateField` is releated to it.
A simplest setting should be:

```
SECRET_KEY = 'secret'
DATABASES = {'default': {}}
DATABASE_ROUTERS = []
TIME_ZONE = None
```

#### 3. `close_old_connections`.

Django framework default run close_old_connections in every request middleware to avoid "[mysql has gone away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away)".

---

**PS**: I have written package to use django orm not in a classic django project, https://github.com/jdxin0/django_db(https://github.com/jdxin0/django_db).
But you should always pay attention to the three problems above.My package use meta class to solve multi db, set `TIME_ZONE=None` and leave `close_old_connections` to user.