# how to use manage.py syncdb outside of Django project, such as in Tornado?

Tags: django, tornado, django-syncdb

I was looking through http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2009/sep/15/using-django-inside-tornado-web-server/ and I thought it was interesting and useful to use parts of Django if we need it in Tornado.

Based on the setup in http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2009/sep/15/using-django-inside-tornado-web-server/ how can we use `manage.py syncdb` ?

Here's what i have tried so far:
I've tried shifting manage.py to the same folder as the tornado project, and ran `manage.py syncdb` but it returns saying that settings.py is not found.

than i tried to move setting.py to the same folder and ran manage.py again. It tells me that no fixtures found. This time round, I have no idea how to configure settings.py since this is not a Django project.

Any advice or thoughts?

=================updates======================

Hi all,
continuing from the above an using advice provided by Agos,
 i've tried running python manage.py syncdb --settings=dj_tornado and it returns

```
`"Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py'` in the directory containing 'manage.py'`. It appears you've customized things.
You'll have to run django-admin.py, passing it your settings module.
(If the file settings.py does indeed exist, it's causing an ImportError somehow.)"
```

So what i did is to run `django-admin.py syncdb --settings=dj_tornado` and it returns `"django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You haven't set the database ENGINE setting yet."`

But the weird thing is that the database engine has been set. How would I go about fixing this? i'm using django 1.2.3 and Tornado 0.2 by the way.

=================updates again======================

Hi all,
i've applied the advice provided by Agos, with a settings.py file in teh same folder as manage.py, and ran the command `django-admin.py syncdb --settings=dj_tornado`. 
I still received the error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You haven't set the database ENGINE setting yet.
```

But i have already configured the database based engine as follows:
in dj_tornado.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure(
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
            'NAME': 'dev.db',

        }
    }
)
```

I'm kind of at my wits end. How do i use syncdb outside of Django project?

Best.

Answer (score 1):

If I got it correctly, you can just use the `--settings` switch to point manage.py to the `dj_tornado.py`, which is your settings file after all

### Update 1

from the help, available at `python manage.py help`:

```
Options:
  --settings=SETTINGS   The Python path to a settings module, e.g.
                        "myproject.settings.main". If this isn't provided, the
                        DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable will be
                        used.
```

So I would try this:

```
python manage.py syncdb --settings=dj_tornado
```

### Update 2

Another error, another update to the answer!
First of all, consider that that blog post is quite old (september 2009). Django's

```
DATABASES
```

setting [has been updated since 1.2](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/settings/#databases).

The syntax in the blog post was:

```
settings.configure(DATABASE_ENGINE='sqlite3', DATABASE_NAME='dev.db')
```

With Django 1.2.X this is surely not correct. This would be the equivalent version:

```
settings.configure(DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'dev.db'
    }
})
```

(sorry for the horrible formatting of the code).

If this *still* won't work, I'd consider creating a “standard” Django settings file to import. But my bet is on the db settings syntax.

### Last update, I swear

Have you tried using django-admin.py again with the new syntax? If so, and still didn't work, a minimal settings.py would be just this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'dev.db'
    }
}
```

You can also keep the original configuration inside dj_tornado.py and use settings.py just to do syncdb.

Comment: hi, may I know how do i use --settings to point manage.py to dj_tornado.py ?

Comment: hi, thank you for your response. I've tried your method and I;ve updated my question. It has some kind of error.

Comment: hi, I've gave your solution a shot. And it gave me an error message "Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py' in the directory containing 'manage.py'. It appears you've customized things.
You'll have to run django-admin.py, passing it your settings module.
(If the file settings.py does indeed exist, it's causing an ImportError somehow.)" May I know what would be the correct way to create a  “standard” Django settings file to import? and how would the folder/file structure look like? Thank you for your help!

Comment: hello, i've tried it and unfortunately it didnt work out. But i've found a nice workaround here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579511/using-only-the-db-part-of-django . It explains the setup and syncdb works!Read the recipe by @KeyboardInterrupt