# Django database API (model layer) without installing django?

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, sqlite, models

I'm starting a new Python project where I'd love to have Django-like control over my database using models and SQLite, but I don't need **all of Django**. Also I don't want users to have to install any dependencies before using my product.

Are there any smaller projects out there that deliver Django-like database models, or is it possible to extract only the model functionality from Django and include it in my project folder so the user doesn't have to worry about it?

Comment: You haven't found anything on this topic? Let me help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937742/use-django-orm-as-standalone , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579511/using-only-the-db-part-of-django

Comment: I found nothing that indicates how I use parts of Django in a project without the user having to install Django. Please remove the downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible to just install Django's ORM without the rest of it. You can install the whole lot and just *use* the ORM, though.

Alternatively you might like to look into one of the standalone Python db wrappers/ORMs. The big one is [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/), and there's also the smaller [SQLObject](http://sqlobject.org/).