# How to use django's ORM as a stand alone package in AWS lambda?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, django-orm, serverless-framework

For starters, I have tried the following posts & they did not help.

[Using Django ORM Inside AWL Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45992303/using-django-orm-inside-an-aws-lambda-function)

[Using Only The Db Part Of Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579511/using-only-the-db-part-of-django/20968008#20968008)

[Django Stand Alone Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/)

Following the django docs and using pieces of the above links I created the following standalone script to use django's ORM.

```
import django
from django.conf import settings



def configure():
    settings.configure(DEBUG=False,
                       DATABASES={
                           # TODO: Change this to environment variables
                           'default': {
                               "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
                               "NAME": "db_name",
                               "HOST": "db_host",
                               "USER": "admin",
                               "PASSWORD": "db_pass"
                           }
                        },
                        INSTALLED_APPS=['my_models']
                       )
    django.setup()
```

In my handler.py file with my registerUser lambda functions

```
from .django_orm.main import configure
configure()

from .django_orm.my_models import AppUser

def registerUser(event, context):
    #Application Logic
    newUser = AppUser()
    newUser.save()
    return True
```

When I run this I get the following error ...

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_models'
```

My directory structure is the following:

```
./myServerlessProject
   ./djangoORM
     ./main.py
     ./manage.py
     ./my_models
       ./__init__.py
       ./models.py
   ./handler.py
   ./serverless.yml
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I get the django ORM to be stand-alone?

Comment: If it were me, I'd use Zappa (https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa) to spin up your barebones Django project on AWS Lambda, with an AWS Virtual Private Cloud and RDS. Then point your settings against the RDS instance credentials.

Comment: I can not use Zappa. The Zappa middleware adds too much lag time for cold starts.

Comment: Have you looked at the keep warm option in Zappa? The only cold start should be the first one. https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa#keeping-the-server-warm