# peewee vs django for DB processing

Tags: python, mysql, django, peewee

Working on a python & Django project with mysql (newbie) 
Trying to figure out if it is preferable to use peewee in the python DB part & Django models in the Django forms or go ahead and use Django for the entire thing

Related answers claim that Django is high overhead but could not find a base for that assumption

Thanks,
Shimon

Answer (score 13):

Author of peewee here.  If you're using Django for it's views, forms, admin, or really *anything*, I would strongly recommend also using Django's ORM also.

Update:

If you want to use Peewee with Django, I've written a module that will automatically translate your Django model definitions into Peewee model classes. You can read about it [here](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#djpeewee).

Comment: I know it was a long time ago but it looks like this feature is now more generic and covered by [pwiz](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#pwiz-a-model-generator)

Answer (score 3):

This is entirely opinionated, but I think you should use Django for the entire thing. It's not that I don't like peewee. On the contrary, it might very well be a better ORM. But I have a few reasons I think you'd prefer the Django ORM:

1. I think the Django ORM is more intuitive for beginners, and covers most use-cases pretty well. In the future, when you feel comfortable with Django in general and the Djagno ORM, it will be easier to learn how to use peewee and see if you prefer it over the default
2. There's a larger community of Django users that don't use peewee over those who do. That means more people being able to help you (and here at SO) and an easier time finding out the answers to any question you will have.
3. I think peewee is more SQL-y in it's syntax, which I find is easier to understand after you learn a little SQL, while using Django's ORM doesn't require vast SQL knowledge besides the very basic stuff

So peewee is a very viable option, but I think you shouldn't start using it straight away, not before you have any problems with the default.

Answer (score 1):

Use of peewee in Django is totally OK. Actually I recently did a project like that. But I still recommend using Django ORM if you do not have some particular reasons to use peewee.

Here are some issues that may occur when you use Peewee in Django:

1. You may need to write your own db middleware and testcase base class to make django work with peewee.
2. A lot of django open source apps will not work any more because they depend on Django ORM.
3. Migrating tables in Peewee is more difficult than Django ORM.

But Obviously Peewee also brings something good:

1. Stand alone Database processing module, if one day for some reason you do not want to use django any more in a project, it could be very easy to reuse all these peewee code.
2. It is much easier to make two or more projects use the same database if you use peewee. And the table structures are totally under your control.

And maybe more. So as conclusion, I would say Peewee is great, but it is still not working perfectly with django now.

Answer (score 0):

OK, Looks good, I'll use the Django ORM after the warm recommendations
Attaching a SO link for future readers that explains how to use the Django ORM as a standalone
[Use Django ORM as standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937742/use-django-orm-as-standalone)

Comment: If @coleifer or my answer helped you, consider marking one of them as the solution