# python manager.py sqlall my app does not recognise my app

Tags: python, mysql, django

Really frustrating, been tackling unsuccessfully for two days already,
Using Django ORM in a python program, trying to working with a mysql DB I have defined

my file structure is

```
|-- mailparser.py
|-- manager.py
|-- myapp
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   `-- models.py
|-- settings.py
```

My manager.py looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print sys.path
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

and my settings.py looks like:

```
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure(
    DATABASE_ENGINE    = "django.db.backends.mysql",
    DATABASE_NAME      = "mydb",
    DATABASE_USER      = "mysqladmin",
    DATABASE_PASSWORD  = "password",
    DATABASE_HOST      = "192.168.1.1",
    DATABASE_PORT      = "3306",
    INSTALLED_APPS     = ['myapp']
)

from django.db import models
from myapp.models import *
```

Trying to perform root@pdsc pdscroot]# python manager.py sqlall myapp
CommandError: App with label myapp could not be found. Are you sure your INSTALLED_APPS setting is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be importing models into settings. But you should be sure to add myapp to the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: removed the import - I get the same result

Comment: Please show that setting. Is it in the same file as the db stuff?

Comment: Yes, the settings.py file is attached above (the one that contains the settings.configure...

Comment: But that doesn't seem to have INSTALLED_APPS at all. And why are you doing settings.configure inside settings.py?

Comment: saw this in SO as well -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937742/use-django-orm-as-standalone