# How to use Django 1.8.5 ORM without creating a django project?

Tags: python, django, orm

I've used Django ORM for one of my web-app and I'm very much comfortable with it. Now I've a new requirement which needs the database but nothing else that Django offers. I don't want to invest more time in learning another ORM like SQLAlchemy.

I think I can still do:

```
from django.db import models
```

and create models, but then without `manage.py` how would I do migration and syncing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Django ORM as standalone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937742/use-django-orm-as-standalone)

Comment: Agree, Question is duplicate of "use-django-orm-as-standalone" and "Use only some parts of Django?" and "using-only-the-db-part-of-django" but the answers are for older versions of django, if I close this question, It would take ages for someone to write answer for latest version and to get it to top 1st or 2nd answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using django for CLI tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088702/using-django-for-cli-tool)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Django 1.11 documentation on how the applications are loaded](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/applications/#how-applications-are-loaded)

For latest django version project structure would be-

```
|--myproject
|--main.py
|--manage.py
|--myapp
|   |--models.py
|   |--views.py
|   |--admin.py
|   |--apps.py
|   |--__init__.py
|   |--migrations
|--myproject
|   |--settings.py
|   |--urls.py
|   |--wsgi.py
|   |--__init__.py
```

You would still need manage.py to run migrations, main.py is your standalone script

```
# main.py
import os
import django
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'
django.setup()
from myapp.models import MyModel
print(MyModel.objects.all()[0])
```

Answer (score 35):

There are a lot of answers out there that work with older versions of Django, but Django is constantly updating and in my research I found no viable answer for Django 1.8/1.9, so I had to roll my own. Here's how you do it:

Project Structure:

```
├── data
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── models.py
├── main.py
├── manage.py
└── settings.py
```

The `data` directory and migrations directory contain empty `__init__.py` files. The sample `models.py` file reads as follows:

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)
```

The `manage.py` file is the typical Django `manage.py` file. Just be sure to change the settings param in `os.environ.setdefault` if you copy it from a fresh `django-admin startproject` command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# manage.py
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

The `settings.py` file requires 3 settings: DATABASES, INSTALLED_APPS, and SECRET_KEY. Refer to Django docs for DBs that aren't SQLite:

```
# settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'sqlite.db',
    }
}

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'data',
    )

SECRET_KEY = 'REPLACE_ME'
```

The real trick is in `main.py`, which will be where you can code against your models. Apparently you have to use `wsgi` to get things working with these two lines:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Here's a sample main.py:

```
# main.py
# Django specific settings
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

### Have to do this for it to work in 1.9.x!
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
#############

# Your application specific imports
from data.models import *

#Add user
user = User(name="someone", email="someone@example.com")
user.save()

# Application logic
first_user = User.objects.all()[0]

print(first_user.name)
print(first_user.email)
```

[This project](https://github.com/masnun/django-orm-standalone) along with [this post](https://www.stavros.io/posts/standalone-django-scripts-definitive-guide/) were helpful starting points for me to find the answer, and my pull request with working code for Django 1.9 was merged, so you can grab the code from masnun's repo now. If you know of a better way, please submit a pull request.

Comment: This answer is perfectly work in recent django-version !! Thanks:)

Comment: is this still relevant for 1.10.1?

Comment: @mattmc3 It doesn't work for me in `Django 1.9.7`, I have this error `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: COMPRESS_ROOT defaults to STATIC_ROOT, please define either`. Do you know why?

Comment: @trex - I cloned the repo at https://github.com/masnun/django-orm-standalone just now and verified that it still all works for me on Python3 and Django versions through 1.10.2. Have you modified your settings.py? Maybe try to clone the repo fresh.

Comment: As of Django 2.0.5 (Python 3.5) this method works, but I get runtime warnings about models being reloaded. A better solution for my setup, was replacing the two `wsgi` lines with `django.setup()`.

Comment: https://github.com/dancaron/Django-ORM works with 3.x.x

Answer (score 11):

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.apps import apps

conf = {
    'INSTALLED_APPS': [
        'Demo'
    ],
    'DATABASES': {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join('.', 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }
}

settings.configure(**conf)
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

Test on django 1.11.x

Comment: Finally this one worked! Most of the answers didnt work for and I was getting 'django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.'

Comment: This answer along with @mattmc3's answer above works with Django 2.1 also. Many thanks!

Comment: would this function as a manage.py file or a settings.py file ?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
import os
# replace project_name with your own project name
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project_name.settings")
django.setup()
from core.models import Customer,Jobs,Payments

# Your script code
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to add `import django`, and then this worked.