# Use django classes outside of Django in normal module

Tags: django, django-models, geodjango

I would like to use Django classes outside of Django framework, like in Jupyter or in any module.
From this [using django model outside of the django framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34300513/using-django-model-outside-of-the-django-framework), I have seen this

```
import django
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("/home/pi/garageMonitor/django/garageMonitor"))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'garageMonitor.settings'
django.setup()

django.contrib.gis.geos
```

It seems there are issues with GAL and geos packages....

Comment: Have you read the part of the documentation that talks about using Django in standalone mode? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage .

Comment: Is geos/GDAL working properly with manage.py (runserver/test/migrate)?  See also django-extensions's [`shell_plus --notebook`](https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=117542061954187&id=100010951810125) command.