# How to use Django models outside of Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33170016/how-to-use-django-1-8-5-orm-without-creating-a-django-project) guide, I am able to use models outside of Django with the following file structure by calling `python main.py`.

```
├── data
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── models.py
├── main.py
├── manage.py
└── settings.py
```

where main.py looks like this:

```
import os, django
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'settings')

django.setup()
from data.models import Foo, Bar #...

print(Foo.objects.all()) #this works fine
```

What I want to do is turn this into a "package" called `db` that looks like this:

```
    ├── data
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   └── models.py
    ├── __init__.py 
    ├── manage.py
    └── settings.py
```

And in the `__init__.py` of the `db` package, I want to do this:

```
import os, django
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'settings')

django.setup()
from data.models import Foo, Bar # ...
from django.db import connection

__all__ = [
    'connection',
    'Foo',
    'Bar', 
    #...
]
```

So I can call the `db` package from `test.py` (which is in the same directory as `db`) like this:

```
import db

print(db.Foo.objects.all()) # this throws an error "no module named data"
```

or like this:

```
from db import Foo

print(Foo.objects.all()) # this throws an error "no module named settings"
```

Is there a way I can use Django's models without having to call:
`os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'settings')`
`django.setup()`

on every page that uses a model?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check out how [Django apps are loaded](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.setup) I think you need to run your setup in your application’s `models.py` or `models/init.py` and not in `db/__init__.py`

> **When Django starts, django.setup() is responsible for populating the
>   application registry.**
>
> setup(set_prefix=True) Configures Django by:
>
> Loading the settings. Setting up logging. If set_prefix is True,
>   setting the URL resolver script prefix to FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME if
>   defined, or / otherwise. Initializing the application registry. This
>   function is called automatically:
>
> When running an HTTP server via Django’s WSGI support. When invoking a
>   management command. It must be called explicitly in other cases, for
>   instance in plain Python scripts.
>
> The application registry is initialized in three stages. At each
>   stage, Django processes all applications in the order of
>   INSTALLED_APPS.
>
> First Django imports each item in INSTALLED_APPS.
>
> If it’s an application configuration class, Django imports the root
>   package of the application, defined by its name attribute. If it’s a
>   Python package, Django creates a default application configuration.
>
> ***At this stage, your code shouldn’t import any models!***
>
> In other words, your applications’ root packages and the modules that
>   define your application configuration classes shouldn’t import any
>   models, even indirectly.
>
> **Strictly speaking, Django allows importing models once their
>   application configuration is loaded.** However, in order to avoid
>   needless constraints on the order of INSTALLED_APPS, it’s strongly
>   recommended not import any models at this stage.
>
> Once this stage completes, APIs that operate on application
>   configurations such as get_app_config() become usable.
>
> Then Django attempts to import the models submodule of each
>   application, if there is one.
>
> **You must define or import all models in your application’s models.py
>   or models/__init__.py. Otherwise, the application registry may not be
>   fully populated at this point, which could cause the ORM to
>   malfunction.**
>
> Once this stage completes, APIs that operate on models such as
>   get_model() become usable.
>
> Finally Django runs the ready() method of each application
>   configuration.

Comment: why do I need my app running/configured to import python code is beyond me, and every time I look at any django decision it is abhorrent, convoluted and antipythonic, models are just models, they describe shape of data, why do they need an app running???

Anyway, thanks for the answer