# Django Rest Framework - re-using models logic when deserializing responses in a python client

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

When developing a REST API using django and django rest framework, it seems to me that there's a step missing at the very end of this chain, **especially if you'll design a python client of that API**:

- define the model of your resources in django
- use DRF's serializers to send your resource over HTTP
- missing: deserialize your resource back in a python model

Let me give a simple example. I declare the following django model with a bit of business logic:

```py
class Numberplate(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=3)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.number} ({self.country_code})"
```

DRF is super powerful when it comes to building the API around that model. However, if I call that API from a python client, it seems that the best I can get as a response from that API will be a simple json without all the logic I might have written in my model (in this case, the `__repr__` method), and I'll have to navigate through it as such.

Continuing my example, here is the difference with and without a proper deserializer:

```
# the best we can do without rewriting code:
>> print(api.get(id=3))
{"numberplate": "123ABC", "country_code": "BE"}

# instead of re-using my __repr__, which would be ideal:
>> print(api.get(id=3))
123ABC (BE)
```

Is there a clean way to stay DRY and write the logic only once?

I've thought about a couple of options which are not satisfactory in my opinion:

- write a django-model-agnostic Numberplate class and make your model class inherit from both `models.Model` and that class
- import your django models in your client ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55247878/how-to-use-django-models-outside-of-django))

Comment: The point of a rest api is that the request and response is the same regardless of the client and source. They are and should be agnostic of one another. How would a python object definition with methods even be sent over http? If you have some logic that is shared between api and client, then by all means, write a library that both use and extend (most like in option 1 in your question). But trying to send the object definition to a client is the wrong path here.

Comment: @bryan60 very good point. I'm not suggesting in any way that any python logic be sent over the network. However, in the case where you want both a REST API and a python API to some service, re-writing all the business logic and deserialization logic for the python client seems wasteful given that it could technically be derived from the server-side models.

Answer (score 0):

One option for you would be to use [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

```
class NumberplateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    display = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Nameplate
        fields = [..., 'display']

    def get_display(self, obj):
        return str(obj)
        # Or you can move your business logic here directly.
        # return f"{obj.number} ({obj.country_code})"
```

Now you should have:

```
>> print(api.get(id=3))
{"numberplate": "123ABC", "country_code": "BE", "display": "123ABC (BE)"}
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but it only works if all of the logic you want to re-use is "property-like", e.g. your methods don't take any arguments. If I had a method `get_nth_digit(self, n)`, this would not work.

Comment: Yup, definitely. You'd have to pass some parameters in from the request to the serializer to allow for that to happen any way.