# How to have a Python script for a Django app that accesses models without using the manage.py shell?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm writing a script to import some model objects into the database my django application uses. In the past I've solved this by running `./manage.py shell` and then `import myscript`. I'm sure there's a better way. I'd like to be able to call a script from anywhere on my HD using `python scriptname.py`, and in the first few lines of that script it would do whatever imports / other operations necessary so that it can access model objects and behave as though it was run using `manage.py shell`.

What do I need to add to my script to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

Based on @Melug's answer, with addition of dynamically setting Python path to address the 'anywhere on my HD' part of the question:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('c:\\my_projec_src_folder')
from myproject import settings
from django.core.management import setup_environ
setup_environ(settings)
```

Comment: The answers to this question are a foot gun. Most people will want to use manage.py because this question turns up broadly for searches, and you don't need to invoke shell to use manage.py. Most people who come here will want this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8047520/108512

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to setup django environment first:

```
from your_project import settings
from django.core.management import setup_environ
setup_environ(settings)
```

At last import your models, everything goes just like django.

Comment: `setup_environ(settings)` is deprecated since Django 1.4! My post below shows an alternative including an example.

Answer (score 157):

Since Django 1.4 you should avoid using `setup_environ(settings)` (post by Melug) because it is deprecated. Use the following instead and you will be able to access your model

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "your_project_name.settings")

# your imports, e.g. Django models
from your_project_name.models import Location

# From now onwards start your script..
```

Here is an example to access and modify your model:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    # e.g. add a new location
    l = Location()
    l.name = 'Berlin'
    l.save()

    # this is an example to access your model
    locations = Location.objects.all()
    print locations

    # e.g. delete the location
    berlin = Location.objects.filter(name='Berlin')
    print berlin
    berlin.delete()
```

Example model:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: This worked for me only after I moved os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "your_project_name.settings") to the line immediately after import os.    Otherwise, this is a much better solution.

Comment: Good point, Peter! Maybe some model imports just work after the `os.environ.setdefault(...)` line. I rearranged the imports in my post, now it should work for everyone.
PS: If you like this solution even better, please vote for it. Thanks!

Comment: Can I do this without an external settings file? That is to say I want to build the models, the connection, and everything in side a single script. I don't care about views...

Comment: @isaaclw I don't believe you can do this without a settings file. If you find a way, please let us know. Btw. my `settings.py` does _not_ handle any views, it handles connection parameters, flags like debug mode, etc. All views are defined inside the `myapp/views.py` and can be accessed by url patterns defined in `urls.py`

Comment: I almost had it, I just needed to set the settings file to something. Currently I have it set to empty string. DATABASES = {} is set appropriately. Then: `os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = ''` and `settings.configure(**locals())` That all comes before `from django.db import models`

Comment: Where in the file directory does this file go?

Comment: @Michael, are you happen to know if this solution cares about DB connection pool settings (e.g. CONN_MAX_AGE)? Just going to use it with long-living process (socket.io server to be more specific) and wondering if it suitable for my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 142):

To get models loaded too, I had to combine this with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26215548/1591957), otherwise I get `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet`

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_project.settings")
import django
django.setup()
```

As an extra, I add this to the `__init__.py` of my django projects, it will automatically discover the app name so it is copy/paste-able:

```
import os


def setup():
    module = os.path.split(os.path.dirname(__file__))[-1]
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "{}.settings".format(module))
    import django
    django.setup()
```

Then I can just do:

```
from <app> import setup
setup()
```

Comment: Thanks, apparently it is required to call setup() since **Django 1.7**.

Comment: The setup() in init is nice, love it!

Comment: This should be the correct answer now. Only solution that works for me.

Comment: I've noticed 2 things: 1) errors are thrown when there are setups in multiple files, 2) setup() doesn't work when called in models.py, otherwise great answer

Comment: @yvesva You shouldn't be calling this from your models.py. This is for initialising django from external scripts. Don't use this within your standard django app call flow. And there shouldn't be any problem with putting this in multiple files? As long as the module path the function gets is appropriate it will work. I'm getting the impression you're not doing this correctly.

Comment: setup() in __init__ is neat! Thanks @rebs

Answer (score 49):

For Django version 1.9 or later you can use this:

```
import sys
import os
import django

sys.path.append('your_project_directory')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'your_project.settings'
django.setup()

from yourapp.models import your_model
```

so you can use object as same django object:

```
from myapp.models import Locations
all_locations = Locations.object.all()
first_location = Locations.object.get(id=1)
print first_location.name()
first_location.save()
```

Comment: This worked for me!  Django 2.0.  Why exactly do we need to append the path with our project directory?  Is there any good info on what django.setup() does high level?

Comment: @timbram - have you found out? is there a way to automate this in text editors like sublime text 3 or atom?

Comment: This is the only solution that works with the latest LTS version (3.2) on Windows.

Answer (score 41):

I think the best way is to create your [custom management command(s)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/). Then you can call `manage.py <yourcommand>` from anywhere.

Comment: Better option in the long run.

Comment: I agree, this is the way to go.  It's not much harder than creating a standalone script, and far more robust.

Comment: Although true, it's still sometimes required to use django models from other scripts.

Answer (score 11):

**FOR DJANGO 1.11**

Upper solutions did not work, but gave me an error:

*django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.*

For me solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27426582/5804947) worked out:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 4):

Since at least Django 1.11, your main app includes a wsgi module that does the neccessary setup on import. Assuming `myproject/myproject` is where your settings.py is, in your script just import:

```py
from myproject.wsgi import application
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer for Django versions > 1.4:

```
from django.core.management import settings
from myproject.myproject import settings as project_settings

if not settings.configured:
  settings.configure(default_settings=project_settings)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you get:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Try:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.settings')
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: I am using a standalone script in Django which is importing the Models. I tried the above technique and I am getting the following error RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant

Comment: @AR7 did you found a way around this error? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: I think the reentrat error happens when you are calling the get_wsgi_application() more than once.

Answer (score 2):

for django >= 2.0 it is enough to do these 2 imports

```
from your_project_path import settings as your_project_settings
from django.core.management import settings
```

then you can do just `from my_app.models import MyModel`

and work with your Model `MyModel`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "mysite.settings"`

if `os.environ.setdefault` doesn't work. (Windows 10, python3.6.4, django 2.0.3)

Answer (score 0):

As Stavros pointed out [here](https://www.stavros.io/posts/standalone-django-scripts-definitive-guide/), you can just copy the wsgi.py and put it at the beginning of you script. Besides setting up DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE, you also need to get the applications. Hope it helps. It works for me at django 2.1.5.

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'revochem.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 0):

Many of the above answers are correct, but don't reference [the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage).

First you need to configure settings or set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` envrionment variable

```py
from django.conf import settings
if not settings.configured:
    settings.configure(myapp_defaults, DEBUG=True)
```

The docs then specify:

> After you’ve either set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` or called
> `configure()` you’ll need to call `django.setup()` to load your
> settings and populate Django’s application registry. For example:
>
> ````py
> import django from django.conf
> import settings from myapp
> import myapp_defaults
>
> settings.configure(default_settings=myapp_defaults, DEBUG=True)
> django.setup()
>
> # Now this script or any imported module can use any part of Django it needs. from myapp import models ```
> ````

The docs also include an important caveat:

> `django.setup()` may only be called once.
>
> Therefore, avoid putting reusable application logic in standalone
> scripts so that you have to import from the script elsewhere in your
> application. If you can’t avoid that, put the call to django.setup()
> inside an if block:
>
> ```py
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     import django
>     django.setup()
> ```