# Django queryset not returning all rows

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Hi I have below setup.

Django 1.9,
mongoDB,
pymongo 2.7,
mongoengine 0.9

I have written an API to store logs at backend server userwise. Below is sample of table

```
user  subject  registered  changed_on
abc    eng      Y          "2018-04-18T00:00:00Z"
abc    maths    N          "2018-04-18T00:10:00Z"
xyz    eng      Y          "2018-04-18T00:10:00Z"
```

I also have read API for this in which we give user name and timestamp for filter like below:

```
{
"user" : "abc",
"from_date" : "2018-04-18T00:00:00Z"
}
```

The line in **serializers.py** which is applying filter is

```
Logs.objects.filter(user__iexact='abc',changed_on__gte=from_date)
```

Now Sometimes when I add new log and retrieve it from postman, it is not working. I have to restart django server and then it gives me newly added row.

I dont understand why this is happening.

EDIT1 : **Full Serializer.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class GetUserLogs(serializers.Serializer):
    user = serializers.CharField(label=_("USER"))
    token = serializers.CharField(label=_("Token"))
    from_date = serializers.CharField(label=_('From date'), default="")
    till_date = serializers.CharField(label=_('Till date'), default=datetime.datetime.now().isoformat().split(".")[0]+'Z')
    def validate(self, attrs):
        user = attrs.get('user')
        token = attrs.get('token')
        from_date = attrs.get('from_date')          
        if user:
            tokendetails = validate_token(token)
            if not tokendetails:
                msg = _('Invalid token.')
                raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)
            else:
                userdetails = tokendetails.user
                if userdetails.check_user(user):
                    rows = Logs.objects.all().filter(user__iexact=user,changed_on__gte=from_date, changed_on__lte = till_date)
                    print(len(rows))
                else:
                    msg = _('Invalid USER)
                    raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)
        else:
            msg = _('Must include "USER".')
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)

        attrs['rows'] = rows
        return attrs
```

Comment: Try to add `Logs.objects.all().filter(user__iexact='abc',changed_on__gte=from_date)` also define the amount of data. Maybe there is any limitation.

Comment: define amount of data how? I am putting from date as optional... but maximum we are going to keep 1 month data in db

Comment: Let us know the result of `len(Logs.objects.all().filter(user__iexact='abc',changed_on__gte=from_date))`

Comment: You need to show the full context of that filter line. If you have to restart your server to see new data, that means you're doing the query at module or class level rather than inside a method.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, can you please explain?

Comment: May be caching issue, you may have used, it is getting, that's why whenever you restart server, it works.

Comment: Not without showing your code. Do that and I'll explain what's wrong with it.

Comment: @AnupYadav, I am not using caching in my code

Comment: Then another issue could be of POSTMAN, sometimes postman goes into the cache, I would suggest use DRF's API interface. Or check through API client code.

Comment: You *are* using caching, albeit inadvertently. As I said, you have something at module or class level. You need to *show your code*.

Comment: @AnupYadav, UI si giving error which we are confirming from postman.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, what minimum code can I show you for your help. Its a secure project

Comment: @PanosAngelopoulosm I tried that but still same issue

Comment: @DanielRoseman, if its ok, we can get on teamviewer session.

Comment: @pratibha If your project is secure you can always put a fake model names and fields in your example.

Comment: Ok, so what code do you need

Comment: @T.Tokic, which part of code do you need?

Comment: You should probably show at least the full serializer.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I have updated the question

Comment: Where is `till_date` defined in that filter? It's not referring to any field value, is there a global definition somewhere?

Comment: @DanielRoseman,from_date and til_date are filters on date column i.e. to get data between 2 dates

Comment: No. Your filter says `changed_on__lte = till_date`. There `till_date` is a variable, which you have defined somewhere.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, Can you please help me in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49852738/django-app-ssl-socket-connection-to-firmware)

Answer (score 0):

So After a lot of debugging for almost a day, I found that the default value of till_date that we are setting to current timestamp of system is not increasing as time increase. So I changed default value to empty string and added below code after reading value of till_date.

```
if till_date == "":
    till_date = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat().split(".")[0]+'Z'
```

It will reset the till_date value to current timestamp every time its value is missing.

Hope it will help someone someday.