# How to import a model to a python file within my django project?

Tags: python, django

I have `models.py` and `test.py` files in my Django app folder.

My project is named `strava`, app: `explorer_api`

How do I import a model into 'test.py`?

I have tried:

```
from strava.explorer_api.models import Activity
from explorer_api.models import Activity
from .models import Activity
from models import Activity
```

but:

> SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative
>   import

The structure:

```
/
    admin.py
    apps.py
    collector.py
    models.py
    serializers.py
    test.py
    tests.py
    urls.py
    views.py
    __init__.py
migrations/
    0001_initial.py
    __init__.py
    __pycache__/
        0001_initial.cpython-35.pyc
        __init__.cpython-35.pyc
templates/
    explorer_api/
        index.html
        save.html
__pycache__/
    admin.cpython-35.pyc
    collector.cpython-35.pyc
    models.cpython-35.pyc
    serializers.cpython-35.pyc
    urls.cpython-35.pyc
    views.cpython-35.pyc
    __init__.cpython-35.pyc
```

Comment: Do you have a `__init__.py` file in explorer_api?

Comment: Yes, I do.....................

Comment: would you mind posting your file structure?

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this [Django script to access model objects without using manage.py shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047204/django-script-to-access-model-objects-without-using-manage-py-shell)
if strava is your project directory then

greater than or equal to Django 1.9-1.10

```
import sys, os, django    
sys.path.append('full_path_to_strava_directory')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'strava.settings'
django.setup()

from strava.activity.models import Activity
```

pre Django 1.11

```
from strava.wsgi import application
from strava.activity models import Activity
```

Comment: I suggest to use `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'strava.settings')`, so that the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` will not be overriden if it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `explorer_api` inside your INSTALLED_APPS?

Also, leave just one import in `tests.py`:

`from explorer_api.models import Activity`