# Django script to access model objects

Tags: python, django, settings

My django project is called mybooks, and the app is listings. I am writing a python script which is named searchBooks.py which needs some of the models in the listings app. The searchBooks.py script is in the listings folder (same as the models.py) However, I cannot access the models.

I did what some other users suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047204/django-script-to-access-model-objects-without-using-manage-py-shell), including

`import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mybooks.settings")
from listings.models import books`

However, I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'listings'

Should I be changing anything in the settings.py? Or maybe the directory of the searchBooks.py?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a script that runs in Django context, invoked through `manage.py`. It's quite easy.

In your app, first create `app/management/commands/__init__.py` (empty file, you may need to make folders). Then, start by copying this template to `app/management/commands/noop.py`:

```
# invoke with ./manage.py noop [--total] 1 2 3 ...
# script in  app/management/noop.py with __init__.py

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command( BaseCommand):

    def add_arguments( self, parser):    # parser is Python argparse parser

        parser.add_argument( 'number_list', nargs='+', type=int,
            help='any number of integers to add up',
        )

        parser.add_argument( '--total', action='store_true', default=False,
            help='Print the total as well as the args'
        )

        parser.add_argument( '--file', type=self.infile)

    def handle( self, *args, **options ):

        # print( f'Args: {args}' )    # what are args?

        if options['verbosity'] >= 2:  # inherit default options, including verbosity and help.
                                       # use --help to explore the others
            print( f'Options: {options}' )

        if options['total']:
            total = sum( options['number_list'])
            print( f'Total: {total}' )

        if options['file']:
            print('First line is:')
            print( options['file'].readline() )


    def infile( self, arg):
        return open( arg, 'r')
```

If you are not familiar with argparse, consult its documntation (it's standard Python, not Django): https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Once you have established that it works and you can get six with

```
./manage.py noop --total 1 2 3
```

copy it as a starting point to some other name in the same folder, and modify it to perform whatever operations you wish to perform from the command line. You'll start by adding

```
from listings.models import Whatever, ...
```

and then modify the handle method to do whatever you want with them, as instructed by whatever options you define.

Django doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: I created the two files, __init__.py and noop.py. However, i am never use the command line for any of my scripts. What do I add to my searchBooks.py (the script that is trying to access the models.py?

Comment: Import it and call it, or cut the code out and drop it into your admin command (within handle, or as a new method that you invoke from handle).

Comment: I think we might be interpreting "script" differently. I thought you meant *shell*  script, i.e. invoke a custom Django operation from the command line or in a cron job, etc.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am learning all of this on my own, and probably using the wrong terminology.  Anyways, I when I mean script, I mean the file. 

I tried running the file searchBooks.py  (which trys to import the models file). But still getting the sample problem. How do I incorporate the noop.py file into it? Just by importing noop?

Comment: Django puts it together. When you do `./manage.py foo`, django looks for a `foo.py` that defines a `BaseCommand` subclass in the subfolder of `management/commands` of any installed app after initializing all Django context. So just take the useful code you have in `searchbooks.py` and paste it into the `handle` method of `listings/management/commands/searchbooks.py`. (except your imports which go at the top). Then invoke the management command  from the command line via `./manage.py searchbooks arguments ...`

Comment: Try something easy first. Modify my noop.py so it fetches and prints some object(s) whose ids get passed as number_list in `noop.py`. You'll just need to import MyModel and replace that sum with a loop `for id in options['number_list']` doing  `MyModel.objects.get(id=id)` and print.