# why I cannot import models to a python script without using django.setup() first

Tags: django

According to this answer ([Django script to access model objects without using manage.py shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047204/django-script-to-access-model-objects-without-using-manage-py-shell)) before I can use Django models in my standalone python script it is enough to point it to the project's settings file:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_project.settings")
from my_app.models import MyModel
```

This results in the error:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

This however works just fine:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_project.settings")
import django
django.setup()
from my_app.models import MyModel
```

I use Django 2.1.7

Is it required now to use `django.setup()` in each script where I use Django models?

Comment: That linked answer doesn't say that at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes. You are required to call `django.setup` if you want to use Django features.

More on [this doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage).