# Django: How to grant user account from user table in excel

Tags: python, django

I want to create accounts with usernames and passwords that are student codes stored in Excel spreadsheets, what should I do?

Comment: Hold on, you store *raw* passwords?

Comment: Sorry for typing my question,I want to create accounts with usernames and passwords that are student codes stored in Excel spreadsheets but the password will be encrypted as usual.

Comment: I tried adding the csv table to the database but with a rough password and could not log in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, export your Excel data as CSV file. Then you can easily iterate through the CSV file using [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html%20csv) library and insert data to Django.

As an example, let's say the fields in the CSV file are like this:

```
name, username, password
```

Then you can use this code to read the CSV file line by line and add users to the database:

```py
def bulk_add_users(path):
    with open('path_to_csv_file', mode='r') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        _ = next(reader)
        for line in reader:
            name = line[0]
            username = line[1]
            password = line[2]
            if not (name and
                    username and
                    password):
                raise ValueError(f'Invalid User data!')
            user = User(name=name, username=username)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
```

Edit:

If you are using django model (or extending it), you should use `user.set_password('raw_password')` so that the password encryption take in place before saving.

Comment: I edited the answer based on your login issue, check that.

Comment: use the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18760222/9733868) or you can create a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/) to run that (if you use this code frequently).

Comment: I just tried it and it worked perfectly, thank you so much Pedram :3

Answer (score 0):

You can create `User` objects with the username and password. For example by processing a csv file where the first column contains the `username`, and the second the *raw* `password`:

```
from csv import reader
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

with open('users.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csvf = reader(csv_file)
    data = []
    for username, password, *__ in csvf:
        user = User(username=username)
        user.set_password(password)
        data.append(user)
    User.objects.bulk_create(data)
```

It is important to use [**`.set_password(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password) here, since that will hash the password in the database.

Comment: Yes, the solution is quite similar to Pedram and it will work, thanks!