# Runtime error:App registry isn't ready yet

Tags: python, django, runtime-error, django-1.7

I am trying to create a script that populates a database with test users. I am new to Django and Python. I keep on getting:

```
Runtime error: App registry isn't ready yet.
```

Here is the output and error:

```
starting population script
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "populate.py", line 32, in <module>
populate()
File "populate.py", line 22, in populate
i.save()
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.7a2-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\base.py",    line 603, in save
force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
...
...
...    
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.7a2-py2.7.egg\django\apps\registry.py", line   156, in get_models
self.check_ready()
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.7a2-py2.7.egg\django\apps\registry.py",   line 119, in check_ready
raise RuntimeError("App registry isn't ready yet.")
RuntimeError: App registry isn't ready yet.
```

Here is the code:

```
import os
import datetime

def populate():
    freer = User.objects.create_user( 'joyyie', 'lolcats@gmail.com', 'e')
    cat = User.objects.create_user( 'steve', 'l2olcats@gmail.com', 'e')
    dog = User.objects.create_user( 'aasd', 'lo3lcats@gmail.com', 'ad')
    cow = User.objects.create_user( 'sadsfa', 'lol4cats@gmail.com', 't' )
    pig = User.objects.create_user( 'regibald', 'lolc5ats@gmail.com', '0')
    donkey = User.objects.create_user( 'turnip', 'lolca6ts@gmail.com', 'pop')
    human = User.objects.create_user( 'tutu', 'lolcat7s@gmail.com', 'pa')
    a = [freer,cat,dog,cow,pig,donkey,human]

    for i in a:
        i.first_name= 'jackee'
        i.is_superuser=True
        i.is_staff=False
        i.date_joined=datetime.datetime.today()
        i.last_login=datetime.datetime.today()

        i.save()


if __name__=='__main__':
    print "starting population script"
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'infosmos.settings')
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    populate()
```

Is there a way to force the user profile creation to wait for the registry app by using a `signal` or something?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## [django 1.7] The Standalone script you wish to run, import django and settings like below

```
import os

import django

[...]


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')

    django.setup()
```

Comment: still a perfect solution to set default environment variable and setup app to resolve app registry problem.

Answer (score 5):

This is a known and intended behaviour according to Django's 1.7 release notes, under the "startup sequence" clause:

> Another common culprit is django.contrib.auth.get_user_model(). Use the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting to reference the User model at import time.

and that should do the trick

for reference:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/#app-loading-changes

Comment: I don't see `django.contrib.auth.get_user_model` used in the above code, and can't imagine how anything in that code could make use of the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting. To me the problem seems more likely with [the missing `django.setup()` call](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/#standalone-scripts).

Answer (score 2):

I found out that if I run populate through the `manage.py` shell with the `execfile()` command then it runs properly. Everything needed to be setup before I start modifying the database or run outside code. Thanks to lanzz for the hint.

Comment: You might want to make this a management command https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-management-commands/