# What is the best way to continuously export information from a Scrapy crawler to a Django application database?

Tags: django, production-environment, scrapy, django-fixtures

I am trying to build a Django app that functions sort of like a store. Items are scraped from around the internet, and update the Django project database continuously over time (say every few days). I am using the Scrapy framework to perform scraping, and while there is an experimental [DjangoItem feature](http://doc.scrapy.org/experimental/djangoitems.html), I would rather stay away from it because it is unstable.

Right now my plan is to create XML files of crawled items with Scrapy's `XMLItemExporter` (docs [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/exporters.html#scrapy.contrib.exporter.XmlItemExporter)), and use those to `loaddata` into the Django project as XML fixtures (docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/django-admin/#loaddata-fixture-fixture)). This seems to be okay because if one of the two processes screws up, there is a file intermediary between them. Modularizing the application as a whole also doesn't seem like a bad idea.

Some concerns are:

- That these files might be too large to read into memory for Django's `loaddata`.
- That I am spending too much time on this when there might be a better or easier solution, such as exporting directly to the database, which is MySQL in this case.
- No one seems to have written about this process online, which is strange considering Scrapy is an excellent framework to plug into a Django app in my opinion.
- There is no definitive guide of manually creating Django fixtures on Django's docs - it seems like it is geared more towards the dumping and reloading of fixtures from the app itself.

The existance of the experimental DjangoItem suggests that Scrapy + Django is a popular enough choice for there to be a good solution here.

I would greatly appreciate any solutions, advice, or wisdom on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit old already, but I'm currently dealing with proper integration of Django + Scrapy as well. My workflow is the following: I've set up Scrapy as a Django management command as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9197627/1125413). Afterwards, I simply write a Scrapy pipeline that saves a scraped item into Django's database using Django's QuerySet methods. That's all. I'm currently using SQLite for the database and it works like a charm. Maybe this is still helpful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use django-dynamic-scraper to create and manage Scrapy scrapers with easy access to Django models. So far I have not run into any problems that it can't solve that Scrapy can't solve.

[Django-dynamic-scraper documentation](http://django-dynamic-scraper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)