# Scrapy and Django import error

Tags: python, django, web-crawler, scrapy

When I am calling Spider through a Python script, it is giving me an `ImportError`:

```
ImportError: No module named app.models
```

My `items.py` is like this:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.contrib.djangoitem import DjangoItem

from app.models import Person

class aqaqItem(DjangoItem):
    django_model=Person
    pass
```

My `settings.py` is like this:

```
#
# For simplicity, this file contains only the most important settings by
# default. All the other settings are documented here:
#
#     http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/settings.html
#


BOT_NAME = 'aqaq'
BOT_VERSION = '1.0'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['aqaq.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'aqaq.spiders'
USER_AGENT = '%s/%s' % (BOT_NAME, BOT_VERSION)
ITEM_PIPELINES = [
                        'aqaq.pipelines.JsonWithEncodingPipeline']

import sys
import os
c=os.getcwd()
os.chdir("../../myweb")
d=os.getcwd()
os.chdir(c)
sys.path.insert(0, d)

# Setting up django's settings module name.
# This module is located at /home/rolando/projects/myweb/myweb/settings.py.
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myweb.settings'
```

My Python script to call the spider is like this:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy import log, signals
from final.aqaq.aqaq.spiders.spider import aqaqspider
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
def stop_reactor():
    reactor.stop()

spider = aqaqspider(domain='aqaq.com')
settings = get_project_settings()
crawler = Crawler(settings)
crawler.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)
crawler.configure()
crawler.crawl(spider)
crawler.start()
log.start()
reactor.run()
```

My directory structure is like this:

```
.
|-- aqaq
|   |-- aqaq
|   |   |-- call.py
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |   |-- items.py
|   |   |-- items.pyc
|   |   |-- pipelines.py
|   |   |-- pipelines.pyc
|   |   |-- settings.py
|   |   |-- settings.pyc
|   |   `-- spiders
|   |       |-- aqaq.json
|   |       |-- __init__.py
|   |       |-- __init__.pyc
|   |       |-- item.json
|   |       |-- spider.py
|   |       |-- spider.pyc
|   |       `-- url
|   |-- call.py
|   |-- call_spider.py
|   `-- scrapy.cfg
|-- mybot
|   |-- mybot
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- items.py
|   |   |-- pipelines.py
|   |   |-- settings.py
|   |   `-- spiders
|   |       |-- example.py
|   |       `-- __init__.py
|   `-- scrapy.cfg
`-- myweb
    |-- app
    |   |-- admin.py
    |   |-- admin.pyc
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |-- __init__.pyc
    |   |-- models.py
    |   |-- models.pyc
    |   |-- tests.py
    |   `-- views.py
    |-- manage.py
    `-- myweb
        |-- file
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- __init__.pyc
        |-- settings.py
        |-- settings.pyc
        |-- urls.py
        |-- urls.pyc
        |-- wsgi.py
        `-- wsgi.pyc
```

Please help me as I am new to Scrapy.

i am real confused 
i tried importing

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myweb.settings
```

in my script at the top new error came that

```
get_project_settings is invalid
```

also my scarapy version is 18

Thank you all i got the solution

Comment: Are both projects (django and scraper) in the PYTHONPATH? Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068308/access-django-models-with-scrapy-defining-path-to-django-project

Comment: i am not sure about scraper but for adding django to the PYTHONPATH i have added this code in settings.py import sys
import os
c=os.getcwd()
os.chdir("../../myweb")
d=os.getcwd()
os.chdir(c)
sys.path.insert(0, d)

Comment: how to add PYTHONVARIABLE Of scraper and where to add it

Comment: + 1 for file structure.

Comment: i am real confused 
i tried importing import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myweb.settings in my script at the top new error came that get_project_settings is invalid also my scarapy version is 18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your problem is that you are importing the spider before the settings. The `ImportError` might come from the `from app.models import Person` in your `items.py`.

So, import your spider after you set up the settings:

```
crawler.configure()

from final.aqaq.aqaq.spiders.spider import aqaqspider
spider = aqaqspider(domain='aqaq.com')

crawler.crawl(spider)
```

Comment: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/spread/jelly.py:92: DeprecationWarning: the sets module is deprecated
  import sets as _sets  it is giving me this error and when i do scrapy version command it is showing me following /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/settings/deprecated.py:26: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: You are using the following settings which are deprecated or obsolete (ask scrapy-users@googlegroups.com for alternatives):
    BOT_VERSION: no longer used (user agent defaults to Scrapy now)
  warnings.warn(msg, ScrapyDeprecationWarning)
Scrapy 0.18.2

Comment: @user2823667 can you explain how you fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I writed this post in the Medium a time ago, perhaps it can help you!

https://medium.com/@tiago.piovesan.tp/make-a-crawler-with-django-and-scrapy-a41adfdd24d9

This is the integrate config between the libs:
***crawler/settings.py***

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), ".."))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myweb.settings'
import django
django.setup()
```