# Scrapy django model import error

Tags: python, django, django-models, scrapy, importerror

I've been trying to set up a scrapy spider using django and djangoitem. When I try running my spider, the item.py always fails to import the django app's model.

I set up a fresh django site and followed the instructions from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19073347/3988392 and I'm still having trouble importing models from my app. I think everything is set up as stated in that thread (except I called things testsite rather than mysite, etc..) But I'll post code if anyone thinks it could be helpful.

Traceback when running `scrapy crawl example`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/scrapy", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Scrapy==0.24.4', 'console_scripts', 'scrapy')()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 143, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 89, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 57, in run
    crawler = self.crawler_process.create_crawler()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/crawler.py", line 87, in create_crawler
    self.crawlers[name] = Crawler(self.settings)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/crawler.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.spiders = spman_cls.from_crawler(self)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 35, in from_crawler
    sm = cls.from_settings(crawler.settings)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 31, in from_settings
    return cls(settings.getlist('SPIDER_MODULES'))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 22, in __init__
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 68, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/myUserName/test-env/testbot/testbot/spiders/example.py", line 3, in <module>
    from testbot.items import UsefulModelItem
  File "/home/myUserName/test-env/testbot/testbot/items.py", line 11, in <module>
    from testapp.models import UsefulModel
ImportError: No module named testapp.models
```

## Filetree:

```
├── testbot
│   ├── scrapy.cfg
│   └── testbot
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __init__.pyc
│       ├── items.py
│       ├── items.pyc
│       ├── pipelines.py
│       ├── settings.py
│       ├── settings.pyc
│       └── spiders
│           ├── example.py
│           ├── example.pyc
│           ├── __init__.py
│           └── __init__.pyc
└── testsite
    ├── manage.py
    ├── testapp
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── models.pyc
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   └── views.py
    └── testsite
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── __init__.pyc
        ├── settings.py
        ├── settings.pyc
        ├── urls.py
        └── wsgi.py
```

Comment: Try including an empty `__init__.py` file in `testapp` directory

Comment: It looks like there was an empty `__init__.py` created when I ran `python manage.py startapp myapp` so I don't think that's whats wrong.

Comment: Where is your models.py? Is it under myapp folder or testapp folder?

Comment: Added a filetree. models.py is under testapp (myapp in Rho's tutorial)

Answer (score 2):

I think you miss to write the pythonpath to your django project. 
You are adding the app, not the project.

in testbot/settings.py add:

```
# Setting up django's project full path.
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/TristanTrim/PycharmProjects/testsite')

# Setting up django's settings module name.
# This module is located at /home/rolando/projects/myweb/myweb/settings.py.
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'testsite.settings'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import os
```

# Setting up django's project full path.

```
sys.path.append('/home/testsite')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'testsite.settings'
```