# How to delete existing objects from DB in python scrapy pipeline?

Tags: python, django, scrapy

> Here my code, in my code, the pipeline only save the item but I tried
>   to delete existing item, it wont work, why this happened?

```
class ProcessPipeline(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.ids_seen = set()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    """

    :param item:
    :param spider:
    :return:
    """
    item['website'] = spider.ref_object
    try:
        delete_item = Modelclass.objects.get(name=item['name'])            
        delete_item.delete()
    except Modelclass.DoesNotExist:
        item['website'] = spider.ref_object
        item.save()            
    return item
```

> Any help appreciable, thank you...

Comment: How have you integrated django ORM with scrappy? https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy-djangoitem http://stackoverflow.com/a/19073347/3033586

Comment: yes, but save() function working fine. but delete() not working.

Comment: I think the problem is in this line then `delete_item = Modelclass.objects.get(name=item['name']) `

Comment: are you commiting to the database?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this line then `delete_item = Modelclass.objects.get(name=item['name'])`

Try debugging that line first. If it's not that, maybe the item is not yielded from the spider. Spider doesn't throw any Exception if it fails to yield an item.

I've tried the delete function. It works.