# Reading existing Django models from inside Scrapy spider

Tags: django, django-models, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I am working on a project where urls are put into a Django model called `UrlItems`. The models.py file containing `UrlItems` is located in the `home` app. I typed `scrapy startproject scraper` in the same directory as the models.py file. Please see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNSbR.png) to better understand my Django project structure.

I understand how to create **new** `UrlItems` from my scraper but what if my goal is to get and iterate over my Django project's **existing** `UrlItems` inside my spider's `def start_requests(self)` function?

**What I have tried:**

1) I followed the [marked solution in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068308/access-django-models-with-scrapy-defining-path-to-django-project) to try and see if my created `DjangoItem` already had the `UrlItem`s loaded. I tried to use `UrlItemDjangoItem.objects.all()` in my spider's `start_requests` function and realized that I would not be able to retrieve my Django project's `UrlItem`s this way.

2) In my spider I tried to import my `UrlItem`s like this `from ...models import UrlItem` and I received this error `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`.

**Update**

After some consideration I may end up having the Scrapy spider query my Django application's API to receive a list of the existing Django objects in JSON.

Comment: Could you post `tree` structure of your project directory?

Comment: Here is an image of the entire tree structure of my project and `home` app. `settings folder` contains project settings python files and `scraper folder` contains the Scrapy scraper project http://i.imgur.com/cKTIayM.png

Comment: @Granitosaurus Added an update