# Django custom management command running Scrapy: How to include Scrapy's options?

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I want to be able to run the [Scrapy web crawling framework](http://scrapy.org/) from within Django. Scrapy itself only provides a command line tool `scrapy` to execute its commands, i.e. the tool was not intentionally written to be called from an external program.

The user [Mikhail Korobov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114795/mikhail-korobov) came up with a [nice solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271975/access-django-models-inside-of-scrapy/9197627#9197627), namely to call Scrapy from a Django custom management command. For convenience, I repeat his solution here:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# myapp/management/commands/scrapy.py 

from __future__ import absolute_import
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def run_from_argv(self, argv):
        self._argv = argv
        return super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        from scrapy.cmdline import execute
        execute(self._argv[1:])
```

Instead of calling e.g. `scrapy crawl domain.com` I can now do `python manage.py scrapy crawl domain.com` from within a Django project. However, the options of a Scrapy command are not parsed at all. If I do `python manage.py scrapy crawl domain.com -o scraped_data.json -t json`, I only get the following response:

```
Usage: manage.py scrapy [options] 

manage.py: error: no such option: -o
```

**So my question is, how to extend the custom management command to adopt Scrapy's command line options?**

Unfortunately, Django's [documentation of this part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-management-commands/) is not very extensive. I've also read the documentation of Python's [optparse module](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) but afterwards it was not clearer to me. Can anyone help me in this respect? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: but shouldn't we be in top directory to crawl ?? How is that done? @pemistahl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I have found a solution to my problem. It's a bit ugly but it works. Since the Django project's `manage.py` command does not accept Scrapy's command line options, I split the options string into two arguments which are accepted by `manage.py`. After successful parsing, I rejoin the two arguments and pass them to Scrapy.

That is, instead of writing

```
python manage.py scrapy crawl domain.com -o scraped_data.json -t json
```

I put spaces in between the options like this

```
python manage.py scrapy crawl domain.com - o scraped_data.json - t json
```

My handle function looks like this:

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):
    arguments = self._argv[1:]
    for arg in arguments:
        if arg in ('-', '--'):
            i = arguments.index(arg)
            new_arg = ''.join((arguments[i], arguments[i+1]))
            del arguments[i:i+2]
            arguments.insert(i, new_arg)

    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
    execute(arguments)
```

---

Meanwhile, Mikhail Korobov has provided the optimal solution. See here:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
# myapp/management/commands/scrapy.py 

from __future__ import absolute_import
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def run_from_argv(self, argv):
        self._argv = argv
        self.execute()

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        from scrapy.cmdline import execute
        execute(self._argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you're really looking for **Guideline 10** of the [POSIX argument syntax conventions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html):

> The argument -- should be accepted as a delimiter indicating the end of options.
>   Any following arguments should be treated as operands, even if they begin with
>   the '-' character. The -- argument should not be used as an option or as an operand.

Python's `optparse` module behaves this way, even under windows.

I put the scrapy project settings module in the argument list, so I can create separate scrapy projects in independent apps:

```
# <app>/management/commands/scrapy.py
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        os.environ['SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = args[0]
        from scrapy.cmdline import execute
        # scrapy ignores args[0], requires a mutable seq
        execute(list(args))
```

Invoked as follows:

```
python manage.py scrapy myapp.scrapyproj.settings crawl domain.com -- -o scraped_data.json -t json
```

*Tested with scrapy 0.12 and django 1.3.1*