# scrapyd unable find Django model

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I am trying to use Django model with scrapy but i am getting this error:

```
sudo scrapy deploy default -p eScraper
Building egg of eScraper-1370598403
'build/scripts-2.7' does not exist -- can't clean it
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Deploying eScraper-1370598403 to http://localhost:6800/addversion.json
Server response (200):
{"status": "error", "message": "ImportError: No module named eScraperInterfaceApp.models"}
```

I have used this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271975/access-django-models-inside-of-scrapy)

It is able to find django project settings.py file but when i tried to import django app model in items.py file i am getting error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another easy way put your scrapy project content into Django project DIR and then you can simply do what you want to do ..with out any problem..But remember to put scrapy project content not scrapy project DIR itself..

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without seeing your code.

You have your path set to '/path/to/django/project/project' ?

You are using djangoitem for your items and importing all your models correctly?

You have wrote an item pipeline?