# Can't run Scrapy project in Django

Tags: python, django, scrapy

Here is my folder layout:

- my_django_project

  - project

    - project

      - __init__.py
      - settings.py
      - urls.py
      - wsgi.py
    - people

      - management

        - __init__.py
        - commands

          - __init__.py
          - scrapy.py
      - migrations
      - __init__.py
      - admin.py
      - models.py
      - tests.py
      - views.py
    - scrapy_project

      - scrapy_project

        - spiders

          - __init__.py
          - my_scraper.py
        - __init__.py
        - items.py
        - pipelines.py
        - settings.py

---

And what I have been doing is following this tutorial: [Access django models inside of Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271975/access-django-models-inside-of-scrapy)

And I followed everything and I still can't do much about it.
Every time I run `python manage.py scrapy crawl my_scraper` it gives me the same error:

> ImportError: No module named scrapy_project.settings

Now I do import the settings in Django's `settings.py`:

```
import os

os.environ['SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'scrapy_project.settings'
```

I have tried different approaches. Now I have been able to connect scrapy with Django models, but I want to be able to run the scrapy project from Django.

Here is my `scrapy.py` in the `commands` folder:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def run_from_argv(self, argv):
        self._argv = argv
        self.execute()

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        from scrapy.cmdline import execute
        execute(self._argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand, you need to move the inner `scrapy_project` package one level up.

Comment: Basically I moved what was in the **first scrapy_project folder** to the top so that it is under  the **second project** folder. Thank You!