# Python - Creating a many-to-one relation between two classes and a method to reference each with the other

Tags: python, class, oop

I have a `Team` class and a `Driver` class.

```
class Team:
  def __init__(self, teamName, drivers=None):
      self.teamName = teamName
      if drivers is not None:
        self.drivers = list(drivers)
      else:
        self.drivers = []
```

```
class Driver:
    def __init__(self, name, country, number: str, podiums: int):
        self.name = name
        self.country = country
        self.number = number
        self.podiums = podiums
```

The `Team` class also has a function to add an instance of the `Driver` class to a particular team.
Each team has two drivers and the drivers can switch teams.
I can access the drivers that belong to a certain team but how do I access the team that a certain driver belongs to without having to manually add a `team` parameter in the `Driver` class?

Comment: Try using a metaclass to create a team attribute/property/field on all corresponding drivers whenever a team instance is created

Comment: Actually we dont need a metaclass. Set "team" attribute of each driver within the init method of "team" using setattr.

Comment: Do you want to avoid adding a `team` attribute *at all*, or is it fine for your project as long as you don't have to do it "manually"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you could could approach such a problem. Many represent a tradeoff between simplicity (and perhaps efficiency) on the one hand, and convenience (or "magic") on the other. Sometimes being straightforward and explicit really is best, even if it seems clunky.

That said... one way you might implement this is to give `Team` a class attribute that's a dictionary listing all `team` instances and their associated `driver` instances. I'm inferring from your question that a driver can only be on one team at a time, and that if possible you'd like that to be enforced as "automatically" as possible. I'm not sure if you want the code to enforce "no more than two drivers per team", perhaps throwing an error if you try to add a third, so I'll leave that aspect out for now.

```
class Team:
    _membership = {} # Stores all teams and their members at the class level.
                     # The underscore indicates it's only intended to be used 
                     # internally by the Team class.
    
    def __init__(self, name, drivers=None):
        self.name = name
        Team._membership[self] = [] # Create an entry in the dictionary, with no drivers
        if drivers is None:
            drivers = []
        for driver in drivers:
            self.add_driver(driver) # Defined below
    
    def __repr__(self):
        """Define how to represent this object in output."""
        return f"<Team '{self.name}', drivers: {self.drivers}>"
```

We need to implement that `add_driver()` method. It will check if the driver's currently on a different team, and if so, remove it there:

```
    def add_driver(self, driver):
        old_team = Team.find_team_for_driver(driver) # Defined below
        if old_team == self:
            # If the driver is already on this team, we're done.
            return
        if old_team is not None:
            # If it was on a different team, remove it from that team.
            old_team.drivers.remove(driver)
        # Lastly, add it to this team.
        Team._membership[self].append(driver)
```

`find_team_for_driver()` isn't attached to a specific instance, but a method for general bookkeeping of the `Team` class, so it's a [class method](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/classmethod-decorator):

```
    @classmethod
    def find_team_for_driver(cls, driver):
        for team, drivers in cls._membership.items():
            if driver in drivers:
                return team
        # Return None if the driver was not found in a team.
        return None
```

We can use a [property decorator](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property) to make it easy to see what drivers a team has:

```
    @property
    def drivers(self):
        return Team._membership[self]
    
    @drivers.setter
    def drivers(self, drivers):
        Team._membership[self] = []
        for driver in drivers:
            Team.update_membership(self, driver)
```

This means we can still use the simple syntax of `team.drivers` and the internals of the `Team` class will handle fetching it from the `_membership` dictionary. Note that while it's tempting to think you could add drivers to a team with `team.drivers.append(new_driver)`, that won't know to remove the driver from their previous team, if any. Make sure to use `team.add_driver(new_driver)` instead.

(Note that `team.drivers.remove(driver_to_remove)` *does* work, but we could define a `remove_driver()` method if desired, just to keep things consistent.)

Okay, we're finally at the `Driver` class, which changes very little. (I've removed all attributes except `name`, just to make this example code a little simpler.) We can use a property to find out what team a driver is in and also to reassign it to a new team:

```
class Driver:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Driver '{self.name}'>"
    
    @property
    def team(self):
        return Team.find_team_for_driver(self)
    
    @team.setter
    def team(self, team):
        team.add_driver(self)
```

---

Testing it out:

```
bob = Driver('Bob')
lisa = Driver('Lisa')
kaya = Driver('Kaya')

red = Team('Red Team', [bob, lisa])
print(red)
=> <Team 'Red Team', drivers: [<Driver 'Bob'>, <Driver 'Lisa'>]>

blue = Team('Blue Team')
blue.add_driver(kaya)
print(blue)
=> <Team 'Blue Team', drivers: [<Driver 'Kaya'>]>
```

Reassigning drivers:

```
lisa.team = blue
red.add_driver(kaya)

print(red)
=> <Team 'Red Team', drivers: [<Driver 'Bob'>, <Driver 'Kaya'>]>
print(blue)
=> <Team 'Blue Team', drivers: [<Driver 'Lisa'>]>
```

---

This kind of infrastructure can be handy for a certain size and complexity of project. For smaller, simpler things, you're probably better off explicitly defining and setting links between objects. (Note that all the iterating though `Team._membership` is slower than referencing explicit object attributes. This may not be enough of a difference to matter, in many cases.)

On the other end of the spectrum, as a project grows more complex, rather than implement more and more of this stuff, an existing system like [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) starts to make more sense. Django's overall purpose is to be a web framework, but even if you're not doing anything web-related, its object-relational system implements all sorts of relations (one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-many), with lots of convenient options like bidirectionality and enforcement of uniqueness. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302651/use-only-some-parts-of-django) if you get to a point where you'd like try that. (I believe [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) implements something similar, but I've not tried it myself.)

Comment: Thanks for such a precise answer! I just wanted to know if `find_team_for_driver(self, driver)` should have been `find_team_for_driver(cls, driver)` ?

Comment: I'm actually going to have to learn class methods so I wasn't sure about this...

Comment: So I was testing the code and I couldn't figure out why you added the `add_driver` method and how it is supposed to be used.

Comment: @windatom In the test code above, if I had used `red.drivers.append(kaya)` instead of `red.add_driver(kaya)`, Kaya would have been added to Red Team, but nothing would have removed her from Blue Team. Does that make sense? (`kaya.team = red` would accomplish exactly the same thing. I coded it such that you have the option to do it from either the `Team` side or the `Driver` side.)

Comment: @windatom Oh, and yes! Good catch on `(cls, driver)`. Edited.

Comment: @windatom Actually your other comment was an even better catch. `add_driver()` was only calling `update_membership()`, which means only one of them is really needed. Refactored to clean it up.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Team:
  def __init__(self, teamName, drivers=None):
      self.teamName = teamName
      self.drivers = list(drivers or [])
      for driver in self.drivers:
          setattr(driver, "team", self)
```

Set the team attribute for each driver as the corresponding "team" instance whenever the team instance is created. Also, add `team = None` to *Driver* class

**Edit**

As @crazychunk pointed out, driver objects can be added to drivers list separately as well and needs to be handled. So, i propose a different solution

```
class Drivers(list):

    def __init__(self, *args, team, **kwargs):
         super(Drivers, self).__init__(*args, *kwargs)
         self.team = team
         for driver in self:
             driver.team = team

    def append(self, p_object):
         super(Drivers, self).append(p_object)
         p_object.team = self.team
       
    def extend(self, iterable):
         super(Drivers, self).extend(iterable)
         for x in iterable:
             x.team = self.team

class Team:
    def __init__(self, teamName, drivers=None):
        self.teamName = teamName
        self.drivers = Drivers(drivers or [], team=self)

class Driver:
    def __init__(self, name, country, number: str, podiums: int):
        self.name = name
        self.country = country
        self.number = number
        self.podiums = podiums
```

So even if new drivers are added to team, the Drivers class will handle setting the team attribute.

Comment: Or more simply: `driver.team = self` Note that this will also have to be done in the method that adds drivers to the team later.

Comment: `setattr(driver, "team", self)` works but `driver.team = self` does the same thing. `settattr` is more useful when you don't know the name of an attribute until runtime. (All that aside, I'm not sure this actually answers the question of not "having to manually add a `team` parameter". I'm waiting to see if they clarify what they mean by that.)

Comment: @CrazyChucky Basically, I want to check what team a driver belongs to and I want that to update automatically if I change a driver's team or add a new driver to a team.

Comment: This solution requires me to add the team argument in the beginning, when I create a `Driver` instance. Is there a way to bypass that?

Comment: You don't have to add a team argument when you create a Driver instance. I have not change the Driver class at all. Please note that I have added another class "Drivers" which is nothing but a list class

Comment: Make sure you're answering the initial question: " how do I *access the `team` that a certain `driver` belongs to* without having to manually add a `team` parameter in the Driver class?" Your edited answer doesn't offer a way to do this.

Comment: It does. Please read the solution carefully. Nowhere does the solution say that you have to add team manually. Setting self.drivers=Drivers(drivers, team=self) in the init of Team will handle everything

Comment: If you downvoted the answer, please state a reason. It is a simple and effective solution